# What is a good XDOC (or C# equivalent) style of program/plug-in for SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, documentation, comments, xdoc

I'm looking for a way to properly comment my stored procedure code so that I can extract the information into useful documentation ala something like XDOC (or C# equivalent). Something that's preferably lightweight would be ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're already using Sandcastle to generate documentation based on the XML comments that Visual Studio generates, you might want to check out the following CodeProject project:

[SQL XML Documentation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SQL_XML_Documentation.aspx)

It shows you how you can use the tools you're already using to generate documentation for your SQL objects in the same style as the documentation you're already generating for the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [extended properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190243(SQL.90).aspx) which can be queried in a simple SQL statement?

```
SELECT * FROM sys.extended_properties
```

No need for any plug-ins, add-ons, or have a specific stored proc layout...

This is what we use for every object in our databases (and we also use [Red Gate SQL Doc](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Doc/index.htm) too to give some structure and a nice web site)

Comment: Because I want to see the comments for the procedure in the procedure itself the same way I see comments with code in my C# programs.

Comment: And have the ability to extract it separately too?